# How to query latitude and longitude of Windows 10 device in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, geolocation

I'm looking for a way to query Windows 10 location service via PowerShell to return the device's current latitude and longitude in decimal notation. Cribbing from http://www.verboon.info/2013/10/powershell-script-get-computergeolocation/ I put together the following function:

```
    function Get-LatLong()
    {
    # Windows Location API
    $mylocation = new-object -ComObject LocationDisp.LatLongReportFactory

    # Get Status
    $mylocationstatus = $mylocation.status
    if ($mylocationstatus -eq "4")
    {
        # Windows Location Status Returns 4, so we're "Running"

        # Get latitude and longitude from LatLongReport property
        $latitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Latitude
        $longitude = $mylocation.LatLongReport.Longitude

        if ($latitude -ne $null -or $longitude -ne $null)
        {

            write-host "$longtitude $latitude"

        }
        Else
        {
            write-warning "Latitude or Longitude data missing"
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        switch($mylocationstatus)
        {
            # All possible status property values as defined here: 
            # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317716(v=vs.85).aspx
            0 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Report not supported"} 
            1 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Error"}
            2 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Access denied"} 
            3 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Initializing" } 
            4 {$mylocationstatuserr = "Running"} 
        }

        If ($mylocationstatus -eq "3")
        {
            write-host "Windows Loction platform is $mylocationstatuserr" 
            sleep 5
            Get-LatLong
        }
        Else
        {
            write-warning "Windows Location platform: Status:$mylocationstatuserr"
        }
    }
} # end function
```

When I call the function, it returns:

> PS C:\windows\system32> Get-LatLong
>
> WARNING: Windows Location platform: Status:Report not supported

Location services are enabled on the device. I am running PowerShell as Admin. Web searching didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the comment in the code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317716(v=vs.85).aspx

It mentions:

> [The Location API object model is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, to access location from a website, use the W3C Geolocation API. To access location from a desktop application, use the Windows.Devices.Geolocation API.]

and that the supported platform is:

> Minimum supported client
>   Windows 7 [desktop apps only]

*Conclusion:*

I think the answer of how to query location data on Windows 10 is to use the [Geolocation API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx).

Comment: I think you're correct. I looked over the docs but can't quite grok how to translate into PS. Got advice? TIA!